# CLIPS compilation

Tags: c, compilation, clips

I would like to compile CLIPS on Windows to get object files necessary to a binding with GNAT Ada.

I have downloaded the package clips_core_source_630.zip which provides core  & makefiles directories

```
makefile.g++
makefile.gcc
makefile.lib
makefile.lib++
makefile.win
```

I tried to compile with MinGW through the commands :

```
mingw32-make makefile.gcc
```

or

```
mingw32-make makefile.g++
```

But the answer is always : Nothing to be done ! And of course no object file has been generated.

What am I doing wrong with that approach ?

Comment: @merlin2011 Ok !!! The true problem was that the right makefile had to copied in the core directory where all .c and .h files are located and then invoked by the mingw-make command. Thank you for the help. Apparently the compilation ran fine with the gcc compiler of the gnat  ada distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the argument to a `make` command is the desired target, not the name of the Makefile.

Since the file given as an argument already exists, there is nothing to be done.

If you want to build the project, try just a simple `mingw32-make` in the directory containing the Makefiles.

If that doesn't work, you can specify the file with `-f`.

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.g++
```

Comment: Ok !!! The true problem was that the right makefile had to copied in the core directory where all .c and .h files are located and then invoked by the mingw-make command.